# info.plist location for localization

Tags: ios

I put info.plist file to English.lproj French.lproj

Info.plist file in building setting I set to 'Info.plist'

if I run app, it reports:

```
error: could not read data from '/Users/mymac/cd-standard/apple/apple_ios/Projects/myapp/myapp 1.0/Info.plist': 
The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

if I change Info.plist file in building setting to 'English.lproj/Info.plist'

it will run correctly

Just wonder if there should be any prefix before 'Info.plist' in Info.plist file in building setting

Your comment welcome

Comment: No prefix required but make sure you have localized the plist file when you localized the other files in your bundle

Comment: I have done localization, just wonder if 'English.lproj/Info.plist' is normal

Comment: This is what happened when i was about to localize my app, so what worked for me was, i opened my backed-up project localized all the files like xibs, plist files everything, i used the tutorial for localization on ray wenderlich site

Comment: but fresh localization does not work while other languages work well, all my fresh file is in French.lproj